# c# interface, abstract class, force inherited class not abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, interface

Is there away to for member which inherit a base class which has an interface to implement that interface.

Some interface

```
public interface ICanWork
{
     void DoSomething();
}
```

some abstract class

```
public abstract Class MyBase : ICanWork
{
     // I do not want to implement the ICanWork but instead want the derived class which inherit it
}
```

class which i inherit the base class

```
public class House : MyBase
{
     // i want the compiler to know that it needs to implement ICanWork 
}
```

This didn't work as i would expect.

**Is the only way to achieve this by putting the Interface on the Class inherit the base class?**

e.g.

```
public class House : MyBase, ICanWork
{
    
}
```

Any useful suggestions?

Comment: You can implement the interface members/methods as abstract in MyBase class.

Comment: @Roman your right i wasn't thinking...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *have* to implement the interface within that class that implements your interface, even if your class is `abstract`. However you can make your implementation of that method also `abstract` which forces all deriving classes to implement it:

```
public abstract Class MyBase : ICanWork
{
     public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

When you now define a class deriving your asbtract base-class you also have to implement that method:

```
public class House : MyBase
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Aa664595(v=VS.71).aspx):

> Like a non-abstract class, an abstract class must provide
>   implementations of all members of the interfaces that are listed in
>   the base class list of the class. However, an abstract class is
>   permitted to map interface methods onto abstract methods

Comment: Marked as the answer even tho i figured out this way on my own.. wasn't thinking, but thanks!